# Table header sortable with AngularJS custom directive using link and scope options

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, typescript, angularjs-scope, html-table

I want to implement an Angular directive to make a table header sortable. I have tried the following:

HTML:

```
<th sortable="headers[0]">
    Company id
</th>
<th sortable="headers[1]">
    Client id
</th>
```

TypeScript Controller:

```
...
$scope.headers = [
    new Models.CampaignTableHeader("companyId", true, "Agency"),
    new Models.CampaignTableHeader("clientId", true, "Client"),
    new Models.CampaignTableHeader("clientName", true, "Client name"),
    new Models.CampaignTableHeader("name", true, "Campaign name")
];
...
```

TypeScript TableHeader Model:

```
export class CampaignTableHeader {
    public asce: boolean;
    public desc: boolean;
    public css: () => string;

    constructor(
        public id: string,
        public sortable: boolean = false,
        public title?: string
    ) {
        if (_.isNull(title) || _.isUndefined(title)) {
            this.title = id;
        }
        this.asce = false;
        this.desc = false;
        this.css = () => {
            var result = this.sortable ? "sortable" : "";
            if (this.asce) {
                result = "sortable-asce " + result;
            }
            else if (this.desc) {
                result = "sortable-desc " + result;
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

TypeScript Main:

```
var cuidApp = angular
.module("mainModule", [])
.controller("mainController", ["$scope", "$http", "$window", "$timeout", "$q", Controllers.MainController])
.directive("sortable", () => {
    return {
        link: (scope: any, element, attrs) => {
            var value: Models.CampaignTableHeader = scope.sortable;
            console.log(scope.sortable);
            var e = $(element);
            e.attr("ng-class", "sortable.css()");
        },
        scope: {
            sortable: "="
        }
    }
});
```

`console.log(scope.sortable)` outputs the expected CampaignTableHeader object. The problem is the `ng-class` directive doesn't have the right scope. I check with the console the scope for the header element and it doesn't have a `sortable` property. Do you know what should I change for it to work?